# Content Type issue with the Discussion Board in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: content-type, administration, discussion-board

I have changed the default content type from 'Discussion' to 'Message' is on the Discussion Board on SharePoint 2010 and reverted to its normal (Now, Discussion is the default content type).

Now, If I click on the 'Add new Discussion',it is referring the Message content type and opening the window without Subject Field and the saved item is not getting displayed (yes, message content type will not be shown in Allitems.aspx page).

How can I get rid this issue? It should refer the Discussion content type for the Add New Discussion link...

Comment: Did you get an proper solution for this? i am facing same problem, only difference is i am creating discussion baord using schema.xml in code and attaching required cT's

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange behaviour. I think it must be a bug.

The only solution I could come up with was to disable the Visibility of the Message type. Then the Add New Discussion link seems to go to the correct form.

Comment: yes, it could be. Now I have a VM and will do a check.